# Dell Blade Server 'Voltage is outside of the allowable range'?

Tags: dell, blade-server

I have 16 Dell M610 blades running in an M1000E chassis, all has been fine since they were installed. However I have just been made aware of the following error messages in the DRAC on one of the blades.

> A bus fatal error was detected on a component at bus 4 device 0 function 0.
>   A bus fatal error was detected on a component at bus 0 device 9 function 0.
>   The mezzanine card C1 PG voltage is outside of range.

Any ideas what causes this or what it means exactly? The error description in the M1000e user guide lists the error but has no cause against it. The blade has a dual port 10GB mezzanine card in it.

Comment: This is a case for a support call to Dell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's going to need a service engineer, power down the blade and get Dell or wherever in to look at it, it's not something you can fix sorry.

Comment: Thats ok, i'll swap it out with a spare blade and see if it happens again. If it does then its chassis related I guess.